# How to find the Cardinality of one set defined by another?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have this info:

$p\left( x\right) =x^{2}-4x-12$

We have Set A defined as follow:
$A=\{\dfrac {x}{2}| P\left( x\right) =0 $}

We have Set B defined as follow:
$B=\left\{ \dfrac {x}{y}| x\in A,y\in A\right\} $

Now I'm asked to find $|B|$.

---

This is what I did:

First I found the values of x for which P(x) = 0. using the sum product method I've found that P(x) = 0  when $x_1 = 6$ or  $x_2 = -2$.

If we we're to define A by listing the elements that would be 
A = {$\dfrac{12}{2}$ , $\dfrac{-4}{2}$}  according to the definition x/2 in order to get 6 and -2. Therefore |A| = 2.

Now knowing this I conclude that B can be defined with only tow elements.
So B = {$\dfrac{\dfrac{12}{2}}{\dfrac{-4}{2}}$ , $\dfrac{\dfrac{-4}{2}}{\dfrac{12}{2}}$}

If we simplify the fractions we get B = {-3, $\dfrac{-1}{3}$} 
therefore |B| = 2.

Is my reasoning correct. Did I find all the elements of B to therefore be able to find the correct cardinality?

Comment: No, you missed $1\in B$ since we can have $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

To find the set $A$, you plug the values of $x$ into the formula $\frac{x}2$. So $$A=\left\{\frac{6}2,\frac{-2}2\right\}=\{3,-1\}.$$ For $B$, you have to plug in all possible pairs of values $(x,y)$ into the formula $\frac{x}y$. So
$$
B=\left\{\frac{3}{3},\frac{3}{-1},\frac{-1}3,\frac{-1}{-1}\right\}=\dots
$$